# xml to yaml: You cannot define a sequence item when in a mapping in

Tags: xml, symfony, yaml

can anybody tell me what's the problem in converting the xml to yaml?(i've tried to do it but i get an error that says "You cannot define a sequence item when in a mapping in ")

```
<service id="sonata.news.admin.post" class="%sonata.news.admin.post.class%">
    <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_blog" label="post"/>
    <argument />
    <argument>%sonata.news.admin.post.entity%</argument>
    <argument>%sonata.news.admin.post.controller%</argument>

    <call method="setUserManager">
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager" />
    </call>

</service>
```

and converted yaml file:

```
sonata.news.admin.post:
    class: "%sonata.news.admin.post.class%"
    arguments: [%sonata.news.admin.post.entity%]
    arguments: [%sonata.news.admin.post.controller%]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: sonata_blog, label: post}
    call:
        - {method: setUserManager}
        service:
            fos_user.user_manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a completely wrong syntax ... please read the documentation i.e. how to use [setter injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection) with YAML.

```
arguments: [%sonata.news.admin.post.entity%]
arguments: [%sonata.news.admin.post.controller%]
```

should be

```
arguments: [%sonata.news.admin.post.entity%, %sonata.news.admin.post.controller%]
```

... further

```
call:
    - {method: setUserManager}
    service:
        fos_user.user_manager
```

... should be

```
 calls: 
     - [setUserManager, ["@fos_user.user_manager"]]
```